# $\mathbb {N}_{0}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ but $\#\mathbb{N}_{0}=\#\mathbb{Z}$? Is this why set theory is "wrong"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I was told this the other day and it kinda makes sense. All of the natural numbers and 0 are also integers, but not all integers are positive or 0. So it follows that $$\mathbb {N}_{0} \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}$$

However, there exists at least one function $f:\mathbb{N}_{0} \rightarrow \mathbb {Z}$ such that $f$ is bijective. That means that $\# \mathbb{N}_{0}=\# \mathbb{Z}$. How can this happen? What is the explanation behind this?

Comment: "Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them." - John von Neumann

Comment: The set $\mathbb{N}$ has an injection $n \to n + 1$ that isn't bijective. Why is that a problem?

Comment: One motto is "counting arguments only work for finite sets" (with care over what is meant by counting - essentially the pigeonhole principle). Every infinite set can be put into bijection with a proper subset of itself. Why does this make set theory "wrong"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially this is the concept of cardinality of infinite sets. Both of the sets you listed are countably infinite, that is, by definition they can be mapped to a subset of the naturals (in this case the improper subset, because we need all of them). Sets of this size are said to be of size $\aleph_0$ (that is the first Hebrew letter "aleph"), which is classified as a transfinite number. It is notable to mention that this infinite cardinality is less than $\aleph_1$, which is associated with the size of $\mathbb{R}$, said to be uncountably infinite (can you prove this?). To denote cardinality, we use vertical bars, for example $\vert \mathbb{N} \vert = \aleph_0$.

The point is, once you are dealing with infinitely many objects, the idea of sets being equinumerous becomes harder to define and must be looked at slightly differently. As one may assume, there are also other "infinities" that can be investigate.

Food for thought: Consider the set of rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$. Which is true $\vert \mathbb{Q} \vert = \aleph_0$ or $\vert \mathbb{Q} \vert = \aleph_1$ and why?

Comment: I'm guessing |Q| = Aleph0 but I'm not sure how to express why. I'd say because all numbers in Q,Z and N can be expressed as fractions of finite integers

Comment: "It is notable to mention that this infinite cardinality is less than $\aleph_1$, which is associated with the size of $\mathbb{R}$." No. $\aleph_1$ is the first uncountable cardinality (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number#Aleph-one) for a bit more on this), but the reals might be quite larger than $\aleph_1$; the statement "$\vert\mathbb{R}\vert=\aleph_1$" is the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), and is not provable or disprovable from the usual axioms of set theory (= ZFC).

Answer (score 0):

[Too long for a comment.]

Another example you might find interesting: each sequence of distinct natural numbers $a_n$ is/induces a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set $A=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. The set $A$ could seem to be way smaller than the natural numbers (particularly if $a_n$ grows fast), but both sets have the *same number of elements* -or the *same size* if you find the wording misleading-, which doesn’t mean that they have the *same elements*.It is simply the way we define equality of cardinal numbers; two sets have the same number of elements if we can compare them, that is if we can count the elements of one of them using the elements of the other, and viceversa (check the [*Schröder–Bernstein theorem*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) if this doesn’t make sense to you and then read it again!).

For another example, you might like to read about [Hilbert’s Hotel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).
Confused? I think it might be a good mental exercise to try to come up with a “better way to define equality of set sizes”. I would be surprised if you don’t end up thinking that the actual definition is the most natural one, if not the only reasonable one.